# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES behavior?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query below. This query finds on database if that particular table is exists in the database. My question is, by using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, is it going to find that table name to the other database? Or in just particular database where you are connected???

`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = N'WebServiceCredentials'`

Comment: which DB is coming left side DB dropdown, it's mean only connected DB

Comment: TABLE_CATALOG column will show the db name and in this case it will be the connected db.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186224.aspx):

> Returns one row for each table in the **current** database for which the
>   current user has permissions

Answer (score 2):

You can view **all the tables for all databases**, but not using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

You can using `system tables`.
You can run this query:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS dbname, * from [?].sys.tables'
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm just asking if my query will return a value in other table..